# Java How to send properly body in request

Tags: java

I try to connect with API from console program writing in Java, but getting 400 bad-request every time.

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://allegro.pl/auth/oauth/device' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic base64(client_id:client_secret)' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id={client_id}'
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AccessToken {

    void getAccessToken() throws IOException {
        String authUrl = "https://allegro.pl.allegrosandbox.pl/auth/oauth/device";
        String userCredentials = "bdc22d4054c04090ae687d4e0e75a7b4:uNHKzbWhwWQYneraAU7yVWHIdLSIw7MmCHkliZOyk7QNeYeRANdQuApJqFNkADcy";
        String basicAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userCredentials.getBytes());

        HttpURLConnection myURL = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(authUrl).openConnection();

        myURL.setRequestProperty("Request Method", "POST");
        myURL.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuth);
        myURL.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        myURL.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outStream = myURL.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, "UTF-8");
        outStreamWriter.write("client_id={bdc22d4054c04090ae687d4e0e75a7b4}");
        outStreamWriter.flush();
        outStreamWriter.close();
        outStream.close();

        int status =  myURL.getResponseCode(); // 200 = HTTP_OK
        System.out.println("Response (Code):" + status);
        System.out.println("Response (Message):" + myURL.getResponseMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: `setRequestProperty("Request Method", "POST");` does nothing.  The HTTP request method is not a header.  Use the [setRequestMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

Comment: Your request’s Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you did not encode your request body accordingly.  Try `outStreamWriter.write("client_id=" + URLEncoder.encode("{bdc22d4054c04090ae687d4e0e75a7b4}", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JaxB` / `JaxRS`

```
/**
 * OAuth2 / OIDC token retrieval response.
 */
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class OAuthServerResponse
{
    @XmlElement(name = "access_token")
    private String access_token;

    @XmlElement(name = "refresh_token")
    private String refresh_token;

    @XmlElement(name = "token_type")
    private String token_type;

    @XmlElement(name = "scope")
    private String scope;

    @XmlElement(name = "tenant")
    private String tenant;

    @XmlElement(name = "id_token")
    private String id_token;

    // empty constructor, getters, setters
}

  private com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource webResource;

  public void init()
  {
      webResource = Client.create().resource(authorizationServerRoot + "/" + tokenEndpoint);
  }

 /**
  * retrieve an access token against the current authorization server
  *
  * @param payload the request payload as String
  * @return an access token
  */
  public OAuthServerResponse getAccessToken(String payload)
  {
    OAuthServerResponse result = null;
    final ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, payload);
    if (response.getStatus() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    {
        result = response.getEntity(OAuthServerResponse.class);
    }
    else
    {
        LOG.error(String.format("%d invalid oauth2 request", response.getStatus()));
    }
    return result;
}
```

payload looks like : `"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=foo&client_secret=bar"`